# How to convert a list of string into a list of dictionary?

Tags: python, string, list, dictionary, tuples

I have to generate a list of dictionary of key, value pair from a list of string. For example I have a list as such

```
my_list = ["John","Google","yes","Sara","TCS","no","John","facebook","yes"]
```

I want the output as follow:

```
[
{"name":"John","company":"Google","avaiable":"yes"},
{"name":"Sara","company":"TCS","avaiable":"No"},
{"name":"John","company":"facebook","avaiable":"yes"},

]
```

Answer (score 6):

You can loop through the list. You can step the variable inside your loop (that is going to be 'i' below) by 3.

```
my_new_list = []
for i in range(0, len(my_list), 3):
    my_dict = {}
    my_dict['name'] = my_list[i]
    my_dict['company'] = my_list[i+1]
    my_dict['available'] = my_list[i+2]
    my_new_list.append(my_dict)
```

Answer (score 2):

Below Code Snippet should do it for you. The idea here is to figure out the length of the list and use list comprehension to build a dictionary of lists. The assumptions are:

- List Length is a multiple of 3
- All items are in the order as expected by your output format

```
my_list = ["John", "Google", "yes", "Sara", "TCS", "no", "John", "facebook", "yes"]
list_len = len(my_list)
dictionary_list = [
    {"name": my_list[i], "company": my_list[i + 1], "available": my_list[i + 2]}
    for i in range(0, list_len, 3)
]
print("dictionary list = %s" % (dictionary_list))
```

**Output:**

```
[{'available': 'yes', 'company': 'Google', 'name': 'John'}, {'available': 'no', 'company': 'TCS', 'name': 'Sara'}, {'available': 'yes', 'company': 'facebook', 'name': 'John'}]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
[
    {"name": item[0], "company": item[1], "available": item[2]}
    for item in [my_list[i : i + 3] for i in range(0, len(my_list), 3)]
]
```

Comment: This would be a better answer if you explained how the code you provided answers the question.